# Shell Scripting - How to unzip a file and edit it by shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vi, unzip

I made a simple shell script to unzip and edit a csv file. the code run well on command line but unable to run on bash script. Which part do I need to modify?

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:~/octave/
read -p "File Date: " fileDate #
filePath="tt_D01_"$fileDate".zip"
csvPath=$fileDate"_01_TR.csv"
unzip -o -j $filePath '*TR.csv'
vi $csvPath -c ':%s/HHI/1' -c ':%s/HSI/2' -c ':%s/MHI/3' -c ':%s/MCH/4' -c ':%s/F/1' -c ':%s/O/2' -c ':wq!'
split -l 1000000 $csvPath
octave --silent --eval "processData('$fileDate')"
```

Here is the result

```
bash test.bash
File Date: 201607
filePath: tt_D01_201607.zip
csvPath: 201607_01_TR.csv
.ZIP.or tt_D01_201607.zipen tt_D01_201607.zip
split: cannot open ‘201607_01_TR.csv\r\r’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding the quotes to have split -l 1000000 "$csvPath"

Comment: `\r` almost always indicates MS Windows was involved either w an editor or FileZilla or other ftp client. On your linux machine, use `dos2unix myScript`. (if you get weird results from your csv, then `dos2unix "$csvPath"` may be required also). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks very much. The problem the problem has been solved after I change it to unix format! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`\r` almost always indicates MS Windows was involved either w an editor or FileZilla or other ftp client. On your linux machine, use `dos2unix myScript`. (if you get weird results from your csv, then `dos2unix "$csvPath"` may be required also). Good luck.
                    – shellter